# How to receive the "referID" parameter from a deep link after installing and launching my iOS app for the first time

Tags: apple-app-site-association, universal-link

**Note**: Please me solution for without using any third party service as like **firebase dynamic link** or **branch.io**.

Our application has a referral feature. If someone clicks the deep link and installs the application, they will be able to earn **rewards** points.
For Android, we have implemented this feature using the **AppLink** mechanism without using any third-party services. For iOS, we have implemented **Universal Links** using **Apple-app-site-association (AASA)**.
We can successfully receive the "referID" query parameter when the app is already installed on the device. However, when the app is not installed and the user is redirected to the App Store, we are unable to retrieve the "referID" parameter after the app is installed.

Can AASA pass query parameters after app install and first launch?

Here's an example of the deep link we are using: *https://ourdomain.com/open?referID=34534535*

We would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue (For IOS app) , either using AASA or alternative mechanisms.

1. I've implemented custom deep links and Universal Links with AASA, but the link behavior isn't working as expected when the app isn't installed.
2. AASA validation is successful, but I'm not seeing the JSON on the device, and App Store redirection and parameter passing aren't working as intended.
   Detailed and informative:

- **I've set up AASA for deep linking, but I'm encountering issues:

  - The AASA file is in the root directory and validated.
  - No JSON is found in sysdiagnoses after clicking the link.
  - Installed app opens and receives params correctly.
  - App Store redirection and parameter passing fail when the app isn't installed.

Requesting specific guidance:

- **Can you help me troubleshoot why AASA isn't working fully? Specifically:

  - Why isn't the JSON stored on the device?
  - How can I fix App Store redirection and post-install parameter passing?**